# In Elixir how do you sort a keyword list by value?

Tags: list, sorting, elixir

I am trying to develop a simple POC in Elixir that requires information storage in a map. The problem is I cannot figure out how to display the map as list sorted by value.

```
defmodule MapUpdater do
    def update_score(map, player, :double), do: Map.update(map, player, 2, &(&1 * 2))
    def update_score(map, player, :halve), do: Map.update(map, player, .5, &(&1 * 0.5))
    def update_score(map, player, :penalize), do: Map.update(map, player, -1, &(&1 - 1))
    def view_scores(map, :top), do: Map.to_list(map) |> Enum.sort_by(???)
    def view_scores(map, :bottom), do: Map.to_list(map) |> Enum.sort_by(???)
end
```

I have tried:

```
Enum.sort_by(&(elem(&1, 1)) > &(elem(&2, 1)))
```

and any number of variations of this, but reading the Documentation over and over is not helping me. Any advice?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Enum.sort_by/2` takes an arity one function that and sorts the input based on the value returned by calling the function on each element, so that should be `|> Enum.sort_by(&(elem(&1, 1)))`.

```
iex(1)> list = [a: 1, b: 2, c: 0, d: 3, e: -1]
[a: 1, b: 2, c: 0, d: 3, e: -1]
iex(2)> list |> Enum.sort_by(&(elem(&1, 1)))
[e: -1, c: 0, a: 1, b: 2, d: 3]
```

There's also a much more elegant way to sort lists of tuples by the value of one of its element: `List.keysort/2`:

```
iex(3)> list |> List.keysort(1)
[e: -1, c: 0, a: 1, b: 2, d: 3]
```

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea how to do this, and yet it was so easy. Can you shed a little insight onto exactly what this sort_by signature means? `sort_by(enumerable, mapper, sorter \\ &<=/2)`  I was trying to use that, but I guess I don't understand what it's supposed to do.

Comment: `mapper` is the function that'll be called on each item of `enumerable`. The value returned by the `mapper` will be compared using the `<=` operator, that is, it'll perform ascending sort. If you pass in `&>=`, it should do a descending sort. (Sidenote: I didn't know `Enum.sort_by` had an optional third argument until you mentioned it!)

Comment: I am very far from giving advices to you, but if you don’t mind you might link functions you mention in the answer to the documentation [`Enum.sort_by/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#sort_by/3), which a) makes it easier for the future visitors to follow the answer and b) as a bonus will discover all the stuff like the arity of the function with additional parameters.